# Pass multiple value to a controller through ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I made a controller that retrieve the the content of a HTTP get and a directive that will display the result, I use them like that :

```
  <div ng-controller="averageAlertController"
       ng-init="service='/alerts/reponseTimeForAFFR';">
    <average-alert-box
         titre="titre"
         pastille="pastille"
         data="data"
         historique="#/dashboard/urlToDashboards"
         logs="#/discover?_g=%urlToLogs"
    />
  </div>
```

you get something that look like that :

[image: average based alert box]

Now I have several page with 50 of those, I want to make an overview page where I will get One box containing a overview of each page

is there a better way to pass it than writing this :

```
<div ng-controller="averageAlertOverviewerController"
       ng-init="services='/alerts/reponseTimeForAFFR, /alerts/reponseTimeForARFG, /alerts/reponseTimeForAEDS, /alerts/reponseTimeForAMOP;">
```

And then making a list in the controller from the string

```
'/alerts/reponseTimeForAFFR, /alerts/reponseTimeForARFG, /alerts/reponseTimeForAEDS, /alerts/reponseTimeForAMOP;'
```

Thanks.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):  
This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. *There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.*

Comment: I would have had to write a controller for each alert, which does not looks efficient